# SQL Stuff with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

Is it possible to use stuff function with a condition.

I'm trying to create a regex pattern from the values in SQL table.

My stuff function looks like this:

```
stuff(name,patindex('%Apple%',name),len(name),'%')
```

But I also need to run

```
stuff(name,patindex('%Mango%',name),len(name),'%')
```

Can I do both in the same stuff function with a OR condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact logic or expected result is not entirely clear, but you could try writing the above using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
STUFF(name,
      CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Apple%', name) < PATINDEX('%Mango%', name)
           THEN PATINDEX('%Apple%', name)
           ELSE PATINDEX('%Mango%', name) END,
      LEN(name), '%')
```

The logic here is to choose the starting point for the `STUFF` operation based on which fruit substring appears first in the name.

Comment: Yup, this is what I was looking for. Thank you. Apologies for the poor description of the question. I was trying to create a regex based on whether I have Mango or Apple in the table. Case just works fine.